# VBA - Insert data in array without dimensioning it

Tags: arrays, vba, text, dimensions

Sometimes I find myself in front of the problem of filling an array without having to dimension it first. Most of the times, I can verify - with a loop - how many times a condition has been verified, `ReDim` my array accordingly and then with **that same very loop** fill the array with data.
 This is (especially with humongous arrays) very time consuming and not optimized.

Today I found myself programmatically "reading" a text file, in which I had to verify how many times a line was repeated before an empty one, without having any clue on how many there could be. I know only that the minimum number of such lines is 1.

The file looks like this:

```
TITLE Very_Much_Potato
INFO lol?
FREQUENCY 123456.7
DEF_DIAG  1 Potato1.TXT
DEF_DIAG  2 Potato2.TXT

ELEMENT  1   0.00    0.00    -300.00     0.250   0.0     6.0     1   2   0.00    0.0     0.0    
ELEMENT  2   0.00    0.00    -200.00     0.500   20.0    6.0     1   2   0.00    0.0     0.0    
ELEMENT  3   0.00    0.00    -100.00     0.750   40.0    6.0     1   2   0.00    0.0     0.0    
ELEMENT  4   0.00    0.00    0.00    1.000   60.0    6.0     1   2   0.00    0.0     0.0    
ELEMENT  5   0.00    0.00    100.00  0.750   80.0    6.0     1   2   0.00    0.0     0.0    
ELEMENT  6   0.00    0.00    200.00  0.500   100.0   6.0     1   2   0.00    0.0     0.0    
ELEMENT  7   0.00    0.00    300.00  0.250   120.0   6.0     1   2   0.00    0.0     0.0    

END
```

I use the following code to "read it":

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim fd As FileDialog, FilePath As String
Dim fst As Object, StringData As String
Dim Name As String, Frequency As Double, DefDiag() As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .Title = "Select the file you would like to import"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Potato File", "*.pot"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        End
    End If
    FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Set fst = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fst.Charset = "utf-8"
fst.lineseparator = 10      ' sets enter as end-of-line separator
fst.Open
fst.LoadFromFile FilePath

StringData = fst.ReadText(-2)  ' -2 to read until lineseparator
Name = Mid(StringData, 7)
StringData = fst.ReadText(-2)
StringData = fst.ReadText(-2)
Frequency = CDbl(Mid(StringData, 11))
Do Until fst.ReadText(-2) = ""
    StringData = fst.ReadText(-2)  ' DEF_DIAG
    DefDiag(i) = Right(StringData, Len(StringData) - InStrRev(StringData, " "))
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Naturally it stops where the `DefDiag` array is beginning to get filled. Any Idea on how not to dimension it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to fill an array without dimension in VBA, but you can use `ReDim Preserve` to redim the array while looping:

```
...

i=1

Do Until fst.ReadText(-2) = ""
    StringData = fst.ReadText(-2)  ' DEF_DIAG
    ReDim Preserve DefDiag(i)
    DefDiag(i) = Right(StringData, Len(StringData) - InStrRev(StringData, " "))
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I would;

- Load the entire file into memory, parsed into an array of lines

  `Open FilePath For Input As #1
      DefDiag = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), ChrW$(10))
  Close #1`
- Allocate a second array the same size as `DefDiag`
- Loop `DefDiag` doing your processing, adding to the next index of the second array when you need to store a value
- When your done `Redim` the 2nd array to truncate its empty tail

Comment: +1 for the help, but I don't like either the `Open FilePath For Input As #1` nor the fact that I need to use 2 arrays. Doing this would not solve the "double loop" problem

Comment: I assumed you were worried about efficiency, this is hard to beat in that regard IMO as its 1 loop & 3 array allocations in total as opposed to an allocation per line. There are also no late bound COM calls to external dependencies.

Comment: Well you have to load the entire file in an array... Isn't this a sort of loop? Then if I have more series of repeating lines, I think I should loop as many times (especially when it comes to my processing - which builds other data sequentially). 
Also I don't know if it is as well efficient as when it comes to few repeating lines: Loop + Redim Preserve should take less time then.

Comment: Aye Split would use a loop, but one implemented in C/++ inside the VB Runtime so would be extremely fast and efficient. Impossible to say without benchmarking a specific case but `Redim preserve` is generally considered to be quite an expensive operation for large arrays as it must take the entire existing array, reallocate, copy and return.

Comment: I don't know if you can understand German, but [here](http://www.aspheute.com/artikel/20001025.htm)'s some guy who `ReDim`ed `Preserve`d an array 5000 times and claims the performance are not so bad. He says that `ReDim Preserve` is built in old VB.NET, so it should be quite efficient.
Do you more info about its "expensiveness"?